# SQL Detect if Inserted or updated on DUPLICATE KEY update and LAST_INSERT_ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am working on a project where i have somewhere to collect and save from facebook user data in db from different sources and i have to update user data if he already exist.

for now, i am saving the facebook_user_id as unique key in a different extra table to be sure that it s the first time the user was detected, and then make some things if it s the first detection.

```
if($dbh->query()) then ...
```

then i have to update user data and get its db id for further uses.

```
$sql = INSERT into users ...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), ...
$uid = LAST_INSERT_ID
```

So what i need is a solution where i can update the user data and detect if insered for the first time or updated by not using the extra table.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: database that i am using  : MySQL (PDO)

Comment: sure i can fetch if user already exist by making a SELECT in place of creating the extra table (maybe it was a  stuped solution :) ) but anywhere i am searching for a more simple and clean solution then making a select